# Does this sequence of terms converge or diverge as n approaches infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, prime-numbers

Does the ratio $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{p_{n}}{n}$$
converge to a defined limit?
Here $p_{n}$ denotes the nth prime number.
Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: No, it grows without bound. I'm trying to think of an elementary proof that does not leverage too much technology.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says that
$
p_n\sim n\log(n)
$; precisely,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\log (n)}=1
$$
So $\frac{p_n}{n}$ grows like $\log(n)$.